What's the max latency for OpenAI models accessed via Azure with provisioned throughput units?
I'm currently using pay-as-you-go on Azure OpenAI and I'm curious to see how switching to provisioned throughput units would improve the latency.
I read:

Predictable performance: stable max latency and throughput for uniform workloads.

What's the max latency for OpenAI models accessed via Azure with provisioned throughput units?
